# What is the IPv6 equivalent of 127.0.0.1

Tags: networking, ip, ipv6, local-area-network, ipv4

The IPv4 address 127.0.0.1 is for the local/current client. What is the opposite of the address in IPv6? I already searched for it, but only found `::1`. Is this the correct one?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it is `0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001` or shorter `0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1` or even shorter `::1`